# WindowsCryptographicException - Keyset does not exist error after deploy on Azure

Tags: .net-core, ssl-certificate, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-keyvault, .net-security

We are hosting a .NET Core 3.1 application using Azure's Web App Service (Service plan: S1: 2) scaled out to 2 instances.
Using .NET data protection we get the certificates by thumbprint from Azure key vault.

**The code snippet which adds data protection**

`public static IServiceCollection AddCertDataProtection(this IServiceCollection services, SigningKeyCertificateOptions certOptions, ILogger log)
{
var primaryCert = Certificates.GetCertificateByThumbprint(certOptions.PrimaryThumbprint, log);
var secondaryCert = Certificates.GetCertificateByThumbprint(certOptions.SecondaryThumbprint, log);

```
         if(primaryCert == null && secondaryCert == null)
         {
             throw new Exception($"Could not load primary or secondary certs. Primary: {certOptions.PrimaryThumbprint}," +
                 $" Secondary: {certOptions.SecondaryThumbprint}");
         }

         IDataProtectionBuilder dataProtectionBuilder = null;

         if (primaryCert != null) {
             dataProtectionBuilder = services.AddDataProtection()
                 .SetApplicationName("AppName")
                 .ProtectKeysWithCertificate(primaryCert);
         }

         if (secondaryCert != null)
         {
             dataProtectionBuilder?.UnprotectKeysWithAnyCertificate(secondaryCert);
         }

         dataProtectionBuilder.PersistKeysToDbContext<ApplicationDataProtectionContext>();

         return services;
     }
```

`

The certificates are found but we are getting the below exception when calling the PersistKeysToDbContext.

`{"Message":"An exception occurred while processing the key element '\"<key id=\\\"XXXX\\\" version=\\\"1\\\" />\"'.","Element":"<key id=\"XXXXXX\" version=\"1\" />","EventId":{"Id":24,"Name":"ExceptionOccurredWhileProcessingTheKeyElement"},"SourceContext":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager","Application":"XXX","ApplicationName":"XXX","HostName":"XXX","Release":"XXXX","Level":"Error","Exception":{"Type":"Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException","Message":"Keyset does not exist","StackTrace":"   at Internal.NativeCrypto.CapiHelper.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer)\r\n   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.get_SafeProvHandle()\r\n   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.get_SafeKeyHandle()\r\n   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(Int32 keySize, CspParameters parameters, Boolean useDefaultKeySize)\r\n   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(CspParameters parameters)\r\n   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.<>c.<GetRSAPrivateKey>b__66_0(CspParameters csp)\r\n   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.GetPrivateKey[T](Func`2 createCsp, Func`2 createCng)\r\n   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.GetRSAPrivateKey()\r\n   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificateExtensionsCommon.GetPrivateKey[T](X509Certificate2 certificate, Predicate`

`{"Message":"An exception occurred while processing the key element '\"<key id=\\\"XXX\\\" version=\\\"1\\\" />\"'.","Element":"<key id=\"XXX\" version=\"1\" />","EventId":{"Id":24,"Name":"ExceptionOccurredWhileProcessingTheKeyElement"},"SourceContext":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager","Application":"XXX","ApplicationName":"XXX","HostName":"XXX","Release":"XXX","Level":"Error","Exception":{"Type":"System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException","Message":"Unable to retrieve the decryption key.","StackTrace":"   at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.EncryptedXml.GetDecryptionKey(EncryptedData encryptedData, String symmetricAlgorithmUri)\r\n   at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.EncryptedXml.DecryptDocument()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.EncryptedXmlDecryptor.Decrypt(XElement encryptedElement)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.XmlEncryptionExtensions.DecryptElement(XElement element, IActivator activator)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager.Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.Internal.IInternalXmlKeyManager.DeserializeDescriptorFromKeyElement(XElement keyElement)","InnerExceptions":[]},"timestamp":"2022-11-10T08:59:48.7435261+00:00"}`

I would like to mention that:

1. The error only appears occasionally, sometimes it occurs only on one instance.
2. We've added the app registration to the key vault's access policies so the application has the correct access rights to retrieve the certificate.
3. We've set WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE to *
4. The certificates are loaded correctly from the key vault in app's TLS/SSL -> Private keys page.
5. The certificate is valid until 03/2023

I am able to reproduce the same issue on local machine by removing the access rights of the current user with mmc.exe -> manage private keys for the certificate.

What configuration are we missing from the app service? Why does it only happen occasionally?
Any advice is more than welcome.

Comment: How do you get the certificate from AKV? You need to retrieve it using a secret and not as a certificate. If using certificate, you will only get the public key part. Also I did blog about something similar at https://www.edument.se/post/storing-the-asp-net-core-data-protection-key-ring-in-azure-key-vault?lang=en  (not the same issue though)

Comment: The certificates are imported from AKV to TLS/SSL settings of the Azure service and saved under the Private Key Certificates (.pfx) tab. The application loads the certificate from there by thumbprint.
The exception is only thrown occasionally.

Comment: are you sure both service instances uses the same Data protection key. Also do remembe that by default the Data protection api tries to create new signing keys every 90 days. Also, you can enable Data protection logging and it will at startup show quite some interesting data. (set it to debug level).